# Insertafter or replace '[' in docker daemon.json using sed or ansible

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed, ansible

File name: docker daemon.json
location: /etc/docker/daemon.json
content:

```
{
    "insecure-registries": [
        "registry1.com:5001",
        "registry2.com"
    ],
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Want to make the above content like this

```
{
    "insecure-registries": [
        "registry0.com:5000",
        "registry1.com:5001",
        "registry2.com"
    ],
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

OR

```
{
    "insecure-registries": ["registry0.com:5000",
        "registry1.com:5001",
        "registry2.com"
    ],
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Tried sed to replace `[` with `["registry0.com:5000",` but no go.
We are using ansible and unfortunately none of their modules like `insertafter` `lineinfile` have been fruitful so far. Either ansible way or bash way of doing it is fine. Appreciate the help.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far, and the output you got (even if it's the wrong one)

Answer (score 3):

The best-practice way to edit JSON files is to use a JSON-aware tool. In this case, `jq` is such a tool, built specifically to be easy to use from shell.

```
jq '."insecure-registries" |= [ "registry0.com:5000" ] + .' \
  <in.json >out.json
```

If you don't have jq handy, Python also has a fully-compliant JSON library, and using it from bash is straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
prepend_registry() {
  python -c '
import sys, json
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
data["insecure-registries"] = sys.argv[1:] + data["insecure-registries"]
json.dump(data, sys.stdout)
' "$@"
}

prepend_registry registry0.com:5000 <in.json >out.json
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ansible, include the file and store the dictionary into the variable *daemon*. For example,

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/daemon.json
        name: daemon
```

gives

```yaml
  daemon:
    insecure-registries:
      - registry1.com:5001
      - registry2.com
    storage-driver: overlay2
```

Either add the item to the list and [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionaries

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        daemon: "{{ daemon|combine({'insecure-registries': ir}) }}"
      vars:
        ir_add:
          - registry0.com:5000
        ir: "{{ ir_add + daemon['insecure-registries'] }}"
```

, or use the parameter [*list_merge*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        daemon: "{{ daemon|combine({'insecure-registries': ir_add},
                                   list_merge='prepend') }}"
      vars:
        ir_add:
          - registry0.com:5000
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  daemon:
    insecure-registries:
      - registry0.com:5000
      - registry1.com:5001
      - registry2.com
    storage-driver: overlay2
```

To make the task idempotent (to prepend the item only once) set the parameter `list_merge='prepend_rp'`

In general, there might be more attributes with additional items declared in a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
  daemon_add:
    insecure-registries:
      - registry0.com:5000
```

In this case, either iterate the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        daemon: "{{ daemon|combine({item.key: val_add}) }}"
      loop: "{{ daemon_add|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        val_add: "{{ item.value + daemon[item.key] }}"
```

, or use the parameter *list_merge*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        daemon: "{{ [daemon, daemon_add]|combine(list_merge='prepend') }}"
```

Create a template

```yaml
shell> cat daemon.json.j2
{{ daemon|to_nice_json }}
```

and update the file

```yaml
    - template:
        src: daemon.json.j2
        dest: /tmp/daemon.json
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries": [
        "registry0.com:5000",
        "registry1.com:5001",
        "registry2.com"
    ],
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    daemon_add:
      insecure-registries:
        - registry0.com:5000

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/daemon.json
        name: daemon

    - set_fact:
        daemon: "{{ [daemon, daemon_add]|combine(list_merge='prepend_rp') }}"

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/daemon.json
        content: |
          {{ daemon|to_nice_json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this

```
sed -e '/insecure-registries/a\
"registry0.com:5000",' daemon.json
```

or

```
sed -e '/registry1/i\
"registry0.com:5000",' daemon.json
```

You can achieve the goal by adding a line before or after a specified line.

Comment: This works only while the JSON stays formatted the same way it is in the original document. If the next version isn't pretty-printed and has everything on one line, for example, it'll generate invalid output.

Comment: (As I mentioned on another, now-deleted answer: One source of frustration in my long-distant past was customers who hand-rolled parsers consuming an API my employer maintained -- we'd make changes that ought to be completely 100% inconsequential -- like updating a serialization library to a version with different whitespace defaults -- and their code would suddenly break and they'd be making support calls and filing tickets; causing that variety of headache for anyone else in the future is not a good place to be).

Comment: Thanks. But this is a one-shot script. If it's not, decoding and encoding as none-formatted JSON assumption would be an inevitable way just as you do.

Comment: If the OP only needed to edit a single file once, they could do it by hand. The _reason_ to script it is to be able to reuse that script against multiple inputs.